# What was Hillary Swank's character's "purpose" in I Am Mother?

Tags: i-am-mother

In Netflix's scifi movie [I Am Mother](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Am_Mother), there's a nameless character played by Hillary Swank. At the end of the movie, she

> is found by one of Mother's droids, who tells her something like (not an exact quote): "Did you ever wonder who was your mother? You had a purpose in life, and now you're no longer needed.". I suppose she was one of Mother's embryos, just like Daughter, and that she was released into the wild because Mother had a plan for her.

So what *was* her purpose? I presume it was

> to teach Daughter a valuable lesson? If so, what was that lesson? Or was it something else?

Comment: The script (Black List 2017) isn't much help. The woman "Drifter" is clearly **not** a clone but merely a useful idiot.

Answer (score 10):

It's very heavily implied that 'Woman' is APx01, the embryo we saw being decanted the day after the "extinction event". The actor's real age (a young-looking forty-four at the time of filming) lines up with the timescale given, which works out to be 38 years at the point that the film opens.

[image]

It's not until the very end of the film that we realise that the opening scene was a ***montage of different children***, showing APx01 being born, APx02 being raised (but acting in a disappointing way, demonstrated by her inability to make origami, her clinginess and her messiness) and finally with us *meeting* APx03 ('Daughter') as the film action starts.

---

As to why APx01 (Woman) was allowed by Mother to survive, this appears to have been a mechanism to allow APx02/Apx03 to meet a real human in a controlled environment, to be returned (at the appropriate [teachable moment](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-teachable-moment-2081657)) in order to demonstrate what she would have become had she not been raised with her new, higher morality.

Woman does an admirable job of reflecting the very worst of humanity; refusing help freely given, offering violence without provocation, telling stories of life in a human community in times of adversity (complete with cannibalism), using someone as a human shield and ultimately scheming and cheating a gullible person purely for her own selfish motives, even at the cost of an innocent life.

At the end Daughter does realise that Woman is no better a mother-figure than Mother (and at least as big a liar, albeit without the Skynet tendencies) and returns to the nest to take on the role that she was *always meant for*, as materfamilias of a new breed of *homo sapiens morum superior*. Meanwhile, Mother terminates APx01 now that her purpose is fulfilled.

Comment: It makes sense and it's where my "valuable lesson" suspicion was going. I got that it was a montage of different people (about the only thing I liked of this movie, I'm afraid) and that Daughter 02, who we saw in the opening scenes, was the one who got incinerated :)