# Is there first-hand evidence for or against this interpretation of the woman (Hillary Swank) from I am mother?

Tags: i-am-mother

In *I Am Mother*, Hillary Swank's character's back story is heavily left to reader interpretation. According to the character herself:

> She was raised as an orphan, adopted by a family, and lived in a cave for some unknown amount of time. The fact that she'd seen *The Tonight Show* suggests she was alive before the extinction event and would remember regular society; however, this is inconsistent with her statement that her adoptive family found her after the event.

It is however implied that:

> She is the first fetus APx01. We can guess this because: 
>  1. We don't know what happened to APx01; there appears to be no evidence (but we do know APx01 was at least gestated)
>  2. The woman bears a striking resemblance to Daughter
> 3. The woman's stated back story implies that some individuals lived through mother's extinction event. This seems unlikely.

The show's creators were very careful not to give obvious primary source (filmed evidence, not character statements) info though as to which way this interpretation could fall. That said, is there any evidence in the film at all that could confirm either interpretation?

Comment: I thought she was lost on purpose by Mother to get the result at the end.

Comment: Discussed at considerable length here; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/214145/what-was-hillary-swanks-characters-purpose-in-i-am-mother

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the original Black List script *Mother*, 'Woman' was merely 'Drifter'. There's no specific indication that she's directly related to 'Daughter' and in the conversation at the end, Mother refers  to her as being the last of an "*outmoded breed*" (i.e. the last free-born human).

> A goliath DROID — nearly identical to Mother — appears silhouetted behind her. Holding the doors in place. Drifter doesn't flinch as it speaks with Mother's voice —
>
> **DROID:** *Have your friends abandoned you?*
>
> Drifter strangles the crowbar.
>
> **DROID:** *Looks to me like you're all alone. The last of an outmoded breed.*
>
> **DRIFTER:** (re: Daughter) *... is she dead?*
>
> **DROID:** *Would it matter if she was?*
>
> **DRIFTER:** *I was never gonna hurt her.*
>
> **DROID:** *And you never will.*

Additionally, Mother admits to having killed her children (plural), indicating that both of her trial children are dead.

> **DAUGHTER:** *You murdered your own children. Because they didn't measure up?*
>
> Mother takes pause. Assesses Daughter's body language.
>   Steps toward her...
>
> **MOTHER:** *But you do, Daughter. That's what makes you special, (beat) Losing them was unfortunate. But you are the product of their sacrifice.*

---

According to an interview with Swank and Ruugard (Woman and Daughter), the idea that Woman and Daughter were clones of each other wasn't injected into the script until after it became apparent to the director that the actors looked highly similar.

> **Yes, you’d be amazing! Okay. I’ve heard some theories about the connection between your two characters, because you do look a bit
>   alike. Any thoughts?**
>
> **Hilary Swank:** ***What’s interesting is that there was nothing in the script about the way we looked physically, it wasn’t written that
>   way. It just ended up like that.*** Clara was cast and then I was cast
>   right before we started filming. Maybe you guys had already started at
>   that point?
>
> **Clara Rugaard:** *I had been in Australia for a week at least.*
>
> **Hilary Swank:** *So you had already been filming for a good ten days. And so then I’m cast, and we got to set and, clearly, we look
>   related. Yeah. And **so the idea of adding that element and some of
>   those ideas that are now in this script, because of the way we look so
>   similar was a nice added dimension that really helped out.***
>
> **Clara Rugaard:** *Yeah, enriched it.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Interview With I AM MOTHER Stars Hilary Swank & Clara Rugaard](https://www.filminquiry.com/interview-hilary-swank-clara-rugaard/)</sup></sub>